# Android google map API key not running in release

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, sha1

I have an application with a Google Maps in the center. However while programming and debugging it all worked fine. Now we created a release application and we found out the current API key is not working.

Now I created a SHA1 key and added my package name to it inside the developer console. It generated a key for me, however this key isn't working either in a release apk.

I tried several things like regenerate it a few times or reinstall the app.

Anyone know what might go wrong?

Comment: What exactly the error you are getting? are you using "Android Key" for displaying the map?

Comment: Do you sign de apk? Release API Key of Google only works in signed APK.

Hope it helps.

Bye

Comment: I have it signed, and i have no error. It just displays a gray screen.

Comment: What kind of key did you create in the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're creating your SHA from the key that you're signing the application with. This SHA will be different than the one that you use for the debug builds.

Make sure that the application is actually getting signed correctly.

Make sure that the package you're providing for the key is correct.

Comment: All are done like they should. Even regenerated the google map key. But it just doesn't work.

Comment: i have the same problem @JordiSipkens , did you managed to fix this ?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, but don't know how I did it since it's been 2.5 years now. Sorry man!